# Look up in a dictionary pop-up window in OSX

Tags: macos, dictionary

Is it possible to call "Look up in dictionary" in OSX from the dictionary pop-up window? It would look like stack or cascade of pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can click on the "Dictionary" header to open the Dictionary app, and then just about any word there you can click to go to its dictionary entry.